# Pdf file damaged on download in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, browser, download

I am using iTextSharp for creating pdf reports (files) and storing those on the web server where my application resides. I am able to create the file, go into the storage folder and open the file without a problem. Notice: The user is not to get the file automatically
downloaded on creation.

I want to give the user the option to download "old" reports from the server with a button. 
This is working fine in IE (10) but not in Chrome and Firefox. I always get the error message: 
There was an error opening this document. The file is damaged and could not be repaired.

I have this image button and on click I send the user to a Generic Handler (since my page contains Update Panels) according to [this post](http://mohyuddin.blogspot.com/2008/07/responsewritreresponsebinarywritre-and.html) (only using it partially for now).

This is the code that actually downloads the file:

```
 public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var _fileName = context.Request.QueryString["fileName"];

        using (var _output = new MemoryStream())
        {
            //var _fileSeverPath = context.Server.MapPath(_fileName);
            context.Response.Clear();
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";// "application/pdf";
            //context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", _fileName.Length.ToString());
            context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(_fileName)));

            context.Response.WriteFile(_fileName);
            context.Response.Flush();
            context.Response.Close();
            context.Response.End();
        }
    }
```

As I said, this works fine in IE but not in Chrome and Firefox. 
When I open the file in Notepad it seams that I only get about 1/3 of the file when downloaded in Chrome and Firefox.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Been trying to resolve this for a few days now..

Comment: What is `_output` good for?

Comment: Try sending an artificial very big (128MB) file. What happens? Still damaged? How much came through.

Comment: If the files stored on the server are correct PDF files when opening them on the server, then iTextSharp created correct PDFs and the problem is caused by something else. I suggest removing the itextsharp tag from the question.

Comment: Sorry, the output was used when I was trying Response.WriteBinary(_output.ToArray()) ...did not work either.
Agree, maybe the iTextSharp tag should not be there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, FINALLY.. I found the solution and it makes me feel like a fool at the same time.. 
Removed context.Response.Close(); ...then everything worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

From [HttpResponse.WriteFile Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dyfzssz9.aspx)

> When this method is used with large files, calling the method might
>   throw an exception. The size of the file that can be used with this
>   method depends on the hardware configuration of the Web server. For
>   more information, see article 812406, "PRB: Response.WriteFile Cannot
>   Download a Large File" on the Microsoft Knowledge Base Web site.

Try this instead:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    var _fileName = context.Request.QueryString["fileName"];
    context.Response.Clear();
    context.Response.Buffer = true;
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    context.Response.AppendHeader(
        "Content-Disposition",
        string.Format("attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(_fileName)));

    using (var fs = new FileStream(_fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(fs, true))
        {
            int length = (int)fs.Length;
            byte[] buffer;

            using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs, sr.CurrentEncoding))
            {
                buffer = br.ReadBytes(length);
                context.Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
            }
        }
    }
    context.Response.Flush();
    context.Response.Close();
    context.Response.End();
}
```

Comment: Will read past the end of the array. Actually, I don't believe that the WriteFile problem is real. It would make this function useless. It is an important function. If it doesn't throw I'd expect it to work.

Comment: The file is not at all large. 44kb

Comment: This is the errors I got after changing the code as you suggested